# VueJS Loop remaining

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js

I have a little problem. I would like to create a loop to display my articles the problem is that. I want it to never be empty basically if I have 0 articles but. I want 10 this one will display 10 skeleton if I have 1 item this will remove 1 skeleton to replace it with my item.

[image: 1]

I don't know if I was clear enough so here is a little picture.
Basically I have 6 dark gray rectangles but if I have 1 item I would only have 5 if I have 6 I would have no dark gray rectangle at all.

Comment: lots of ways from merging/computing into fixed length array to `v-for="i in 10"` with a if/else v-if="items[i]" template etc, what have you tried?

Comment: Very well thanks you (sorry i have miss click in your comment) **Ibrahim mahrir**

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
<transition-group name="fade" tag="div" class="badge__grid">
        <template v-for="(n, i) in badges.data">
          <div :key="n + i" class="badge__item">
            <img
              class="badge__item--picture"
              :src="
                'https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/' +
                  n.badge_code +
                  '.gif'
              "
              :alt="n.badge_code"
            />
            <span class="badge__item--code">
              {{ n.badge_code }}
            </span>
          </div>
        </template>
        <div
          v-for="i in badges.remaining"
          :key="i"
          class="badge__item badge__item--empty"
        ></div>
      </transition-group>
```

It works but I find it too many and I can't simplify my code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two loops. Using a computed property you can simplify it a bit further:

```
<div v-for="a in articles" >
<h4>{{a.title}}</h4>
</div>
<div v-for="r in remaining" >
</div>
```

and the computed property:

```
remaining(){
    let rem = 10 - this.articles.length;
    return(rem > 0?rem:0)
  }
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-cherry-vy9fw?file=/src/components/Looper.vue:516-599